# Letter Word Sequence Riddle

Tags: word, word-sequence

A 3x3 box is given to you with two blank squares. You have to fill a letter in each to form a nine lettered word beginning from one of the corners and ending in the middle while going clockwise.

[image]

Can you do it?

Answer (score 12):

The word is:

> **AVALANCHE**  starting in top right corner.

Comment: @FattiKhan - I notice that you removed the green check mark. Does that mean this answer is incorrect?